# Starting with Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I am fairly new to Overleaf. The last I used was Tex and that too was very basic. I have a template to work with but when I try to edit it, the TOC (Table of Content) is not updating. I tried making a new chapter with and without an asterisk(*) but after my compilation, it is also not showing up.

I also want to make a folder of all my chapters in it to clean up the pane but the moment I made a new folder and moved my Abstract.tex in it, it has disappeared altogether.

The template that I have, has titles of chapters. So for instance, Introduction, Abstract, Background etc. and when I try to rename these in the pane on the left say Chapter1_Introduction, it also disappears.

If anyone can please direct me to any tutorials where I can solve these problems?

Comment: It's difficult to help you with this description. Unless we can access to your project or a similar one we can just try to imagine what your are explaining. In any case, Overleaf offers you a lot of tutorial, faqs, and email account for help. They always answered all my questions.

Comment: Seems like you need to learn basic LaTeX. When you change the filename, you have to change the file name inthe source as well. The same goes for directories.

Comment: I work on the support team at Overleaf, and I'd just like to recommend writing to us at support@overleaf.com for this or similar questions. If you send us the URL of your project, we'll be able to see what's going wrong directly and tell you what corrections are needed. To ask on tex.sx it's necessary to include an example piece of code that demonstrates the issue, since no one can see your source code otherwise.